# customize Twitter timeline with JQuery and CSS on Load more tweets & MutationObserver implementation

Tags: jquery, twitter, timeline, mutation-observers

I've got this jquery that customizes my Twitter timeline on my website:

```
jQuery('.twitter-block').delegate( '#twitter-widget-0','DOMSubtreeModified propertychange', function(){customizeTweetMedia();} );
var customizeTweetMedia = function()
{ 
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('p.timeline-tweet-text').css('margin', '0');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('img.Avatar').css('display', 'none');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('span.TweetAuthor-screenName').css('display', 'none');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('span.TweetAuthor-Name').css('display', 'none'); 
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.Icon--heart').css('margin', '5px 0 0 -35px');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.Icon--heart').css('font-size', '11px');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.Icon--share').css('font-size', '11px');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.Icon--share').css('margin-left', '-35px');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.Icon--twitter').wrap('<a href="//twitter.com/name" />');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.Icon--twitter').attr('title','@name on Twitter');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.Icon--twitter').attr('aria-label','@name on Twitter');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.timeline-Tweet-inReplyTo').parent('div.timeline-Tweet').css('display', 'none');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.timeline-Tweet-retweetCredit').css('display', 'none');
}
```

When the user scrolls down to the bottom of the timeline and clicks 'Load More Tweets' it doesn't pass the new tweets through the jquery. How can I do this?

I think I need something to the effect of

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").on("click", function(customizeTweetMediaai));
  });
});
</script>
```

But it doesn't seem to work ...

==

Trying the MutationObserver with:

```
jQuery('.twitter-block').delegate( '#twitter-widget-0','MutationObserver observe', function(){customizeTweetMedia();} );
var target = jQuery('.twitter-block');
var customizeTweetMedia = function()
{ 
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('p.timeline-tweet-text').css('margin', '0');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('img.Avatar').css('display', 'none');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('span.TweetAuthor-screenName').css('display', 'none');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('span.TweetAuthor-Name').css('display', 'none'); 
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.Icon--heart').css('margin', '5px 0 0 -35px');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.Icon--heart').css('font-size', '11px');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.Icon--share').css('font-size', '11px');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.Icon--share').css('margin-left', '-35px');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.Icon--twitter').wrap('<a href="//twitter.com/name" />');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.Icon--twitter').attr('title','@name on Twitter');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.Icon--twitter').attr('aria-label','@name on Twitter');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.timeline-Tweet-inReplyTo').parent('div.timeline-Tweet').css('display', 'none');
  jQuery('.twitter-block').find('.twitter-timeline').contents().find('div.timeline-Tweet-retweetCredit').css('display', 'none');
}
var observer = new MutationObserver(customizeTweetMedia);
observer.observe(target);
```

but it just breaks it ...

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the tweets haven't loaded when you call `customizeTweetMediaai` on the button click. Also, it looks [DOMSubtreeModified is depreated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified). Instead you could use the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) api:

```
var target = jQuery('.twitter-block');
var observer = new MutationObserver(customizeTweetMedia);
observer.observe(target);
```

Comment: Oh, so is there a way to call customizeTweeMedia onload?

Comment: On load of the new tweets? MutationObserver will watch the dom so any changes resulting from clicking the Load New Tweets button will trigger `customizeTweetMedia`.

Comment: So how do I actually implement the code. I've tried adding the above code but it just breaks it ...

Comment: It's a little difficult to help you troubleshoot when you only say it "breaks". What errors do you get in the console? Also, are you using [createTimeline](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/timelines/guides/profile-timeline) to generate the twitter timeline?